# Cognos - value prompt to display months from january to current month based on year

Tags: javascript, java, analytics, cognos, cognos-bi

I have a month prompt which is cascaded from year. For current year , month prompt should display from january to current month and for past years, the prompt should display  from january to december. Please let me know how to achieve.

Also is it possible to set the default values as Jan to current month in multi select value prompt.

Thanks
MJ

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple matter of ensuring the query used to populate the value prompt returns only the values you want.

Set the "Default selections" property to "January".

Answer (score 0):

> > month prompt should display from january to current month

You have a month prompt with a query that has the following data items

- Year
- Month

Add the following data items to the query

Current Year defined as

```
extract(year, Current_Date)
```

Current Month defined as

```
extract(month, Current_Date)
```

Create an optional filter on the query for the prompt of the month

```
(?PrmYear? <> [Current Yr]) OR
(?PrmYear? = [Current Yr] and [Month] <= [Current month])
```

> > Also is it possible to set the default values as Jan to current month in multi select >> value prompt.

Just use the default property on the value prompt